# std::async - std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I understand what `std::async` does with the following parameters.

- `std::launch::async`
- `std::launch::deferred`

However what happens with, `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A launch policy of `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred` means that the implementation can choose whether to apply a policy of `std::launch::async` or `std::launch::deferred`. This choice may vary from call to call, and may not be decided immediately.

An implementation that always chooses one or the other is thus legal (which is what gcc does, always choosing deferred), as is one that chooses `std::launch::async` until some limit is reached, and then switches to `std::launch::deferred`.

It also means that the implementation can defer the choice until later. This means that the implementation may wait to make a decision until its hand is forced by a call that has visibly distinct effects from deferred and async tasks, or until the number of running tasks is less than the internal task limit. This is what [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk) does.

The functions that force the decision are: `wait()`, `get()`, `wait_for()`, `wait_until()`, and the destructor of the last future object referencing the result.

Comment: What, gcc always uses `deferred`? Nice, so much to "let the implementation decide what's best for you" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Chaprer 30.6.8 of ISO IEC 14882-2011 explains that `launch::async | launch::deferred` means `implementations should defer invocation or the selection of the policy when no more concurrency can be effectively exploited` (same as `async` without `policy` parameter).

In practice it means that C++ runtime should start new threads for each `async` as long as there are unused CPU cores.

Comment: Yea I saw that, but what does that mean in practice?

Comment: Found the followig quote which made it clearer for me: "it is up to the implementation whether to perform asynchronous execution or lazy evaluation."

Comment: Offtopic: But what happens with deferred launches when `.get()` is never called and the future is simply destroyed?

Comment: Obviously, they are just silently destroyed.

Comment: So a `std::async` call without any arguments does not in any way guarantee that it will actually executed. That is a bit of a gotcha, in the case of "fire-and-forget".

Comment: That's right. Using `async` without `get` makes no sense. If you need "fire-and-forget", start a thread (and detach it).

Comment: That depends, on if the `std::async` implementation uses some form of thread-pool, in which case it would be advantageous over simply start a thread and detach.

Comment: Actually, you can get some sort of "fire-and-forget" with RAII. Just guarantee that `get` would be called in the destructor of some object, containing the `future`.

Comment: Or, just pass `launch::async`?

Comment: `launch::async` is not always the best solution: it may perform somewhat worse than automatic selection of launch strategy. And, what is worse, deleting the `future` may kill your thread.

Comment: "deleting the future may kill your thread", that sounds strange.

Comment: Why is it strange? As far as I know, `future` owns the `thread`, which is joinable, so destructing the `future` means destructing `thread` object, which will call `terminate()` for this thread.

Comment: as far as I know calling ´terminate()´ on a thread leads pretty much to undefined behavior, which is why I cannot see any implementation that would do that, instead of simply letting it run until it's done.

Comment: Calling `tetminate()` in the joinable `thread`'s destructor is required by the standard. Any conforming implementation would do that.

Comment: I understand, what is the behavior of `terminate`? Does it simply interrupt the thread and leave it in an undefined state, or does it do some kind of other magic?

Comment: The behavior of terminate is to simply interrupt the thread. But I was mistaken about `future`'s implementation. It joins the thread before destructing it. So `future`'s destructor will just wait for thread's completion. No problem here.

Comment: Ok! That makes more sense to me.

Comment: `std::terminate()` terminates the **application**, much like `abort()` does.